Flutter web trackpad right/left swipe not working for going backward or forward of the current page
I have create a flutter application. I am using in both mobile and web.
But in web, I want to use trackpad for navigating pages forward/backward just like other websites eg - Gmail and many more etc.
how to achieve that this in flutter web ??
I am using GetX and GoRouter for web for navigating
To Navigate Forward/Backward using trackpad in flutter web.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
